# Debug assertion failed C++ while deleting a pointer vector

Tags: c++, debugging, assertion

I have been working on this for a while now and it may all just be turning into mush. I am a beginner in C++ and I am running into a problem when calling delete to delete the elements in my array. It says that the debug assertion failed. In my book and in the web I found that they are doing exactly what I am so I am not sure why I am getting this failure. Can anyone help? 
Plus, I wouldn't be opposed to some improvement tips.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include "Account.h"
#include "Person.h"
#include "Checkings.h"
#include "Savings.h"
#include "AccountException.h"
using namespace std;


void printAccountSummary(const vector<Account> &acc);
string TYPE;

int main()
{
    cout << "Project 3 - Greg Mora - 601\n" << endl;
    cout << "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%\n" << endl;
    cout << "The Avenger's Retirement Fund\n" << endl;
    cout << "#\tAccount Name \t\tAddress \t\tBalance\n" << endl;

    vector<Account*> acc;

    acc.push_back(new Savings(new Person("Bilbo Baggins", "43 Bag End"), 1, 500, 0.075));
    acc.push_back(new Checkings(new Person("Wizard Gandalf", "Crystal Palace"), 2, 1000.00, 2.00));
    acc.push_back(new Savings(new Person("Elf Elrond", "Rivendell"), 3, 1200, 0.050));

    ofstream dataOut("Accounts.txt");
    if (dataOut.bad())
        cout << "Error: File was unable to open." << endl;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < acc.size(); i++)
    {
        acc[i]->writeData(dataOut);
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < acc.size(); i++)
    {
        if (acc[i] != nullptr)
        {
            delete acc[i];
            acc[i] = nullptr;
        }
    }

    dataOut.close();
    acc.clear();

    try
    {
        ifstream dataInput;
        dataInput.open("Accounts.txt");
        if (dataInput.fail())
        {
            cout << "Error: File was unable to open." << endl;
        }

        while (!dataInput.eof())
        {
            getline(dataInput, TYPE);
            if (TYPE=="Savings")
            {
                Account* save = new Savings;
                save->readData(dataInput);
                acc.push_back(save);
            }
            else if (TYPE == "Checkings")
            {
                Account* check = new Checkings;
                check->readData(dataInput);
                acc.push_back(check);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (AccountException e)
    {
        dataOut.close();
        cout << e.getMessage();
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < acc.size(); i++)
    {
        acc[i]->makeWithdrawl(100.00);
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < acc.size(); i++)
    {
        acc[i]->makeDeposit(25.00);
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < acc.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << acc[i]->getAccountNumber() << "\t" << acc[i]->getPersonInfo()->getName() << "\t\t" <<
            acc[i]->getPersonInfo()->getAddress() << "\t\t" << acc[i]->getAccountBalance() << endl;
    }

    cout << endl << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Person.cpp

```
#include "Person.h"
using namespace std;

Person::Person(){
    name = "";
    address = "";
}

Person::Person(string nameIn, string addressIn)
{
    name = nameIn;
    address = addressIn;
}

string Person::getName() const{
    return name;
}

string Person::getAddress() const{
    return address;
}

void Person::writeData(ofstream& output) const
{
    output << name << endl;
    if (output.bad())
    {
        throw AccountException("Unexpected error occurred during writing out of data");
    }
    output << address << endl;
    if (output.bad())
    {
        throw AccountException("Unexpected error occurred during writing out of data");
    }
}

void Person::readData(ifstream& input)
{
    getline(input, name);
    if (input.bad())
    {
        throw AccountException("Unexpected error occurred during reading in of data");
    }
    getline(input, address);
    if (input.bad())
    {
        throw AccountException("Unexpected error occurred during reading in of data");
    }
}
```

Account.cpp

```
#include "Account.h"
#include "Person.h"
#include "Checkings.h"
#include "Savings.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

Account::Account()
{
    accountNumber = 0;
    personInfo = nullptr;
    accountBalance = 0;
}

Account::Account(Person *personInfoIn, int accNumIn, double accBalIn)
{
    accountNumber = accNumIn;
    personInfo = personInfoIn;
    accountBalance = accBalIn;
}

int Account::getAccountNumber() const
{
    return accountNumber;
}

double Account::getAccountBalance() const{
    return accountBalance;
}

Person *Account::getPersonInfo() const{
    return personInfo;
}

void Account::makeDeposit(double depositAmt){
    accountBalance = accountBalance + depositAmt;
}

void Account::makeWithdrawl(double withdrawlAmt){
    accountBalance = accountBalance - withdrawlAmt;
}
Account::~Account(){
    if (personInfo != nullptr)
    {
        delete[] personInfo;
        personInfo = nullptr;
        accountBalance = 0;
        accountNumber = 0;
    }
}
```

Savings.cpp

```
#include "Savings.h"
#include "Account.h"
using namespace std;


Savings::Savings()
{
    accountBalance = 0;
    intRate = 0;    
}
Savings::Savings(Person *personInfoIn, int accNumIn, double accBalIn, double intRateIn)
:Account(personInfoIn, accNumIn, accBalIn)
{
    intRate = intRateIn;
}
double Savings::getAccountBalance() const
{
    return accountBalance + (accountBalance * intRate);
}
void Savings::readData(ifstream & input)
{
    personInfo = new Person;
    personInfo->readData(input);
    input >> accountNumber;
    if (input.bad())
    {
        throw AccountException("Unexpected error occurred during reading in of data");
    }
    input >> accountBalance;
    if (input.bad())
    {
        throw AccountException("Unexpected error occurred during reading in of data");
    }
    input.ignore();
}
void Savings::writeData(ofstream & output) const
{
    output << "Savings" << endl;
    personInfo->writeData(output);
    output << accountNumber << endl;
    if (output.bad())
    {
        throw AccountException("Unexpected error occurred during writing out of data");
    }
    output << getAccountBalance() << endl;
    if (output.bad())
    {
        throw AccountException("Unexpected error occurred during writing out of data");
    }
}
```

Checkings.cpp

```
#include "Checkings.h"
#include "Account.h"
using namespace std;


Checkings::Checkings()
{
    accountBalance = 0;
    monthlyFee = 0;
}
Checkings::Checkings(Person *personInfoIn, int accNumIn, double accBalIn, double monthlyFeeIn)
: Account(personInfoIn, accNumIn, accBalIn)
{
    monthlyFee = monthlyFeeIn;
}
double Checkings::getAccountBalance() const
{
    return accountBalance - monthlyFee;
}
void Checkings::readData(ifstream & input)
{
    personInfo = new Person;
    personInfo->readData(input);
    input >> accountNumber;
    if (input.bad())
    {
        throw AccountException("Unexpected error occurred during reading in checking account number");
    }
    input >> accountBalance;
    if (input.bad())
    {
        throw AccountException("Unexpected error occurred during reading in checking account balance");
    }
    input.ignore();
}
void Checkings::writeData(ofstream & output) const
{
    output << "Checkings" << endl;
    personInfo->writeData(output);
    output << accountNumber << endl;
    if (output.bad())
    {
        throw AccountException("Unexpected error occurred during writing out checking account number");
    }
    output << getAccountBalance() << endl;
    if (output.bad())
    {
        throw AccountException("Unexpected error occurred during writing out checking account balance");
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of doing for loops with an index "i", use iterators.  If you're using c++ 11, which is looks like you are, you can use a range for loop as well.  As for the actual problem, I presume its on this line? "delete acc[i];".  What line does the assertion issue occur on?

Comment: So you suggest I check for nullptr before I run the three loops in the end?

Comment: My other problem is that if I comment out the loop that deletes the elements and sets to nullptr the program runs. If I leave them as shown above, it crashes at the delete call.

Comment: If you run in a debugger, where *in your code* does the crash happens? If in a loop, at what element index? What happens in the destructors of the `Savings`, `Checkings` and `Person` classes?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - I just added the cpp's
The crash happens right on the delete acc[i] line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that I see:

You are using `operator new` to create `Person` but you are using `operator delete []` to delete it. Change

```
Account::~Account(){
    if (personInfo != nullptr)
    {
        delete[] personInfo;   // Problem
        personInfo = nullptr;
        accountBalance = 0;
        accountNumber = 0;
    }
}
```

to

```
Account::~Account(){
    if (personInfo != nullptr)
    {
        delete personInfo;
        personInfo = nullptr;
        accountBalance = 0;
        accountNumber = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are the best! That solved my issue. I am not going to lie I feel stupid for doing that since I copied and pasted. I know not to do it and I haven't done so, but why I did it this time; who knows?

Answer (score 0):

You have a loop early in the program where you delete the elements in the `acc` vector and set the pointers to `nullptr`, however this does not remove the elements from the vector. Then at the end of the program you have three loops that loops over *all* elements in the vector (including the ones you destroyed) and dereferences the pointers without checking for `nullptr`.

Dereferencing a `nullptr` leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and most likely your crash.

There are two possible solutions that comes to mind: Either clear the vector after the destruction loop, or add checks for `nullptr` in the other loops.

Comment: my problem is that I can't even get passed delete so it actually never calls the next line which is setting nullptr. If i comment out that block of code it works just fine.(i know that causes a memory leak but it was just an observation)

Comment: There is a line to clear the vector - `acc.clear();`.